# jQuery.fn.each to create JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json, each

The following uses `jQuery.fn.each` to build a variable that will contain a JSON Object. The trouble is that adding to the array causes a JavaScript error.

```
var formfields = { step: $(this).data('step') }

$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input').each(function(){
    formfield += $(this).attr('name'):$(this).val(); // This line is the problem
});

alert(form fields);
```

How would this be done.

Comment: Do you really need an object or are you just trying to get the data to pass to an ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
var formfields = {
    step: $(this).data('step')
}
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input').each(function () {
    formfield[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); // This line is the problem
});
alert(JSON.stringify(formfield)); //use console.log() instead of alert()
```

- Look at using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of calling .parent() so many times
- Also you can use `this.name` to access the input's name instead of using `$(this).attr('name')`

Comment: Still need a semicolon on line 3. Additionally, line five adds to `formfield`, which doesn't exist. The `alert` at the end also needs attention: `form fields` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var formfields = {step: $(this).data('step')};

$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input').each(function () {
    formfields[$(this).prop('name')] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(formfields);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way using `serializeArray()`:

```
var formfields = { step: $(this).data('step') };

var formfieldsarray = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input').serializeArray();

$.each(formfieldsarray, function() {
    formfields[this.name] = this.value;
});
```